Using edef to define a variable name that depends on a parameter
I am trying to create a plain TeX macro \p#1#2 where #1 is the text of a problem and #2 is the text of its solution.  It should do the following:

Advance the value of \pno by 1. (\pno is a previously defined counter that stores the problem number.)

Print the value of \pno and the contents of #1.

Store the contents of #2 as a variable called \solxxx  where xxx is the current value of \pno , so that I can insert these contents at some later point in the document.


Here is one of my many failed attempts:
\long\def\p#1#2{\advance\pno by 1  
    \vskip 3pt \item{\bf \the\pno.}#1
      \global\expandafter\csname sol\the\pno \endcsname
                        \global\edef\sol\the\pno   {\item{\bf sol\the\pno.} #2}

I had hoped that when \pno is equal to, say, 214, that this would create a variable called \sol214 that expands to the solution text.  Instead it creates a variable called, literally, "\sol\the\pno".
What should I have done instead?

the first thing you should have done, would be to provide a complete example and not only some snippet people need to extend first before they can test. But apart from this: you should not use \edef or \xdef on arbitrary user input. This will explode. And to define a command with numbers in it, use \expandafter\gdef\csname sol\the\pno\endcsname{text}.

Do it in two steps:
\newcount\pno

\long\def\p#1#2{%
  \vskip 3pt
  \advance\pno by 1
  \item{\bf \the\pno.}#1
  \expandafter\definesol\expandafter{\the\pno}{#2}%
}
\def\definesol#1#2{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname sol#1\endcsname{\item{\bf sol#1} #2}%
}
\def\printsol#1{\csname sol#1\endcsname}

\beginsection Exercises.

\p{Text of the exercise}{Solution of the exercise}

\beginsection Solutions.

\printsol{1}

\bye

The \definesol macro is passed the first argument expanded.

Comments
\global\expandafter\csname sol\the\pno\endcsname does nothing at all except possibly throwing an error, because \global is out of place.
You actually don't get an error because the control sequence created by \csname isn't defined and so leaves \relax in the input stream; \global is still waiting for something that looks like an assignment and it ignores \relax tokens; thus it sees \global and two \global in a row are the same as one. Good! Now TeX finds \edef and is happy to use \global, but you're just defining \sol to be followed by the exact tokens \the\pno and so you simply overwrite preceding definitions of \sol.
You cannot do \def\sol214{something} (\edef, \gdef or \xdef would be the same). More precisely, you can do it, but this would erase a previous \def\sol213{something}. You need \csname sol214\endcsname (with some \expandafter trickery), but you still cannot do \sol214 and hope it expands to the text of the solution; see the helper macro I defined instead.
Using \edef or \xdef is generally dangerous, unless you have precise control of what goes in the to-be-expanded replacement text. This is why I use \gdef with the trick of first expanding \the\pno before passing it to \definesol.


it creates a variable called, literally, "\sol\the\pno".

no you are simply redefining \sol.
\global\expandafter\csname sol\the\pno \endcsname

here \expandafter is applying to s so doing nothing and \global does nothing as there is no assignment. so that line can be
\csname sol\the\pno \endcsname

conversely
  \global\edef\sol\the\pno   {\item{\bf sol\the\pno.} #2}

globaly defines \sol to be a macro that must be followed by the tokens \the and \pno
you presumably meant
 \expandafter\xdef\csname sol\the\pno\endcsname   {\item{\bf sol\the\pno.} #2}

so the \expandafter expand \csname to make the token sol12  (if the counter is 12) which then gets globally edef defined by \xdef you might want
\noexpand\item so that \item rather than its definition gets stored.
This is assuming that you do need an edef (xdef) as that restricts the tokens that may be supplied as #2 as most arbitrary token lists are not safe to expand in an \edef \gdef would be safer (or simply \def if you do not need a global definition).

Thank you, though I still can't quite make this work.  I eliminated the \global\expandafter in my third line and replaced my fourth line with the line you said I "presumably meant", but if I execute this with the counter set to 1 and then type "\sol1", I still get "Undefined control sequence".     Egreg's solution is working for me, though.

@WillO sure I just concentrated on what was wrong with your code lines (as you provided no usable example I did not attempt to guess what the output or fully corrected version would be) egreg guessed a solution rather then saying what was wrong, both are hopefully useful:-)

The undefined command is because in your original you use the command on line 2 and define it on line 3 so it is undefined the first time. @WillO

Ah.  Thank you.   I should have seen this.  I'm most grateful for the education.

If e-TeX is fine I'd use the following instead of \gdef as shown by egreg:
\newcount\pno
\protected\long\def\p#1#2%
  {%
    \advance\pno by 1  
    \vskip 3pt \item{\bf \the\pno.}#1%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname sol\the\pno\endcsname
      {\noexpand\item{\noexpand\bf sol\the\pno.} \unexpanded{#2}}%
  }

% This is syntactic sugar allowing you to use `\sol<num>` as if it was a macro
% name, any other definition of \sol and \solDo would break this usage however.
\protected\def\sol{\begingroup\afterassignment\solDo\count0=}
\protected\def\solDo{\expandafter\endgroup\csname sol\the\count0\endcsname}

\p{foo}{bar}

\sol1

\bye

If you don't use e-TeX you could still make your \p work without an auxiliary using a temporary register assignment:
\newcount\pno
\newtoks\ptoks
\long\def\p#1#2%
  {%
    \advance\pno by 1  
    \vskip 3pt \item{\bf \the\pno.}#1%
    \begingroup
      \toks0={#2}%
      \expandafter\xdef\csname sol\the\pno\endcsname
        {\noexpand\item{\noexpand\bf sol\the\pno.} \the\toks0}%
    \endgroup
  }

% This is syntactic sugar allowing you to use `\sol<num>` as if it was a macro
% name, any other definition of \sol and \solDo would break this usage however.
\def\sol{\begingroup\afterassignment\solDo\count0=}
\def\solDo{\expandafter\endgroup\csname sol\the\count0\endcsname}

\p{foo}{bar}

\sol1

\bye

